# Proper Proof for Completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ with the Euclidean Metric

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry

My code can't be uploaded because it doesn't work with the websites coding, but here is a pdf of my LaTex code. My question is, is this a proper proof? It feels as if I'm missing something important. Perhaps defining $m$ to be the max of the $N_1,\ldots,N_n$? [image]

Edit:

Let $\{( x_{n,1},x_{n,2},\ldots,x_{n,m})\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}^m$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Thus we have that:
\begin{align*}
\forall \thickspace \{( x_{n,1},x_{n,2},\ldots,x_{n,m})\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}},\thickspace \rho(x_{n,k},x_{m,k}) < \epsilon.
\end{align*}
Then each $ \{( x_{n,1},x_{n,2},\ldots,x_{n,m})\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}\}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$. Since each Cauchy sequence is in $\mathbb{R}$, then by completeness of $\mathbb{R}$, we have that:
\begin{align*}
\exists \thinspace y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_m \in \mathbb{R} \thickspace \mbox{and} \thickspace N_1,N_2,\ldots,N_m \in \mathbb{N}\thickspace (\mbox{depending on}\thickspace \epsilon) \thickspace \mbox{such that} 
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
&\forall \thinspace k\in \mathbb{N} : 1\leq k \leq m : \forall \thinspace n_k > N_k : \rho(x_{n,k},y_k) < \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{m}}
\end{align*}
Following from above, we have that by definition of $\rho$ and the fact that $\rho(x,y) \geq 0$, that:
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^m|x_{n,k}-y_k|^2} < \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{m}}& \implies \sum_{k=1}^m|x_{n,k}-y_k|^2 < \frac{\epsilon^2}{m} \\
&\implies |x_{n,k}-y_k|^2 < \frac{\epsilon^2}{m} \\
&\implies |x_{n,k}-y_k| < \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{m}}.
\end{align*}
But we know that $|x_{n,k}-y_k|$ is just a sequence of real numbers and we know that $(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$ is a complete metric space, so $|x_{n,k}-y_k|$ converges in $\mathbb{R}$. More specifically, each $x_{n,k} \rightarrow y_k$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$. This is true due to:
$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (x_{n,1},x_{n,2},\ldots,x_{n,k}) = (\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_{n,1},\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_{n,2},\ldots,\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_{n,m}) = (y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_m)\in\mathbb{R}.
\end{align}$

Answer (score 1):

One way to see that there’s a problem is to notice that you never actually used the crucial hypothesis that the original sequence is Cauchy. I’ll give you an outline for the proof; see if you can fill in the details.

- You have the original Cauchy sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, where $x_n=\langle x_{n,k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$. Use the fact that it’s Cauchy to show that each of the coordinate sequences $\langle x_{n,k}:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ for $k=1,\ldots,m$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb R$.
- Use the fact that $\Bbb R$ is complete to show that for each $k\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$ there is a $y_k\in\Bbb R$ such that $\langle x_{n,k}:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\to y_k$.
- Now show that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\to\langle y_1,\ldots,y_m\rangle$ in $\Bbb R^m$.

Comment: I changed the proof beginning a little.

Comment: @Frumpy: You still haven’t made the essential first step of showing that the coordinate sequences are Cauchy, so your assertion that the $y_k$s exist is unjustified.

Comment: That is what I am having trouble with. I know I need to show each $k$ is Cauchy but I'm not sure how

Comment: Does that fix some of it?